# chaning filename on upload from input form

Tags: php

Hello I am using the following code to upload files on my server and to write the filename inside the database. My question is how I can achive when the file is uploaded the name of the file to be changed ? Right now I am facing a problem if the filename have space sbetween the words if it is not a whole word the file is not uploading correctly.

here is the code:

```
 $target = "../images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
 $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))

 //resize function 
 createThumbnail($filename);
```

Comment: Try to escape spaces in file names: $filename = str_replace(' ', '\ ', $target.basename($_FILES['photo']['name'])); Maybe, it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the filename removing all unwanted characters. The easiast way is to use preg_replace forbidden characters. Here's an example:

```
// List of forbidden chars (\ and / need to be escaped with \)
$forbiddenChars = "\/\\?%*:|\"<>. ";

//Characters not allowed are replaced by this var
$replaceStr = "_";

$filename = preg_replace("/[$forbiddenChars]/", $replaceStr, $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//DEBUG: Test if everything is ok (should be deleted in production)
var_dump($filename);
```